# SVN ignore within external

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals, svnignore

In my repository I have a main project where C files and headers are together in the same folder.

```
MainProject/
| source/
| | file1.c
| | file1.h
| | file2.c
| | file2.h
| other/
```

Now, in another project, in the same repository, I would like to have **only the headers** from this project in a folder as external, so they are synchronized and I get updates from "MainProject"

```
OtherProject/
| includesFromMainProject/    (external from MainProject/source)
| | file1.h
| | file2.h
| source/
```

How can I do this automatically to get all header files from one folder **ignoring all c files** only on the external copy? Is there anyway to do it with Tortoise SVN?

Comment: -I can modify the main project SVN properties, but not its structure.
-I know I can include as external single files, but I am looking for a way to do it automatically for every header file, in case there are new files created in the main project.